# (VBA) How To Assign A Columns Cell To Corresponding Group, and Paste Group Cells into Group Sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to create a vba script-

Link to workbook [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByUcHTNcynugWDN2VW5oQ0V6eGc/view?usp=sharing)

I have a list of Keywords in Column B, and each **Keyword** corresponds to a **Group** in Column A:

[image: input_data]

**How do I group each list of Keywords into it's corresponding Group's worksheet, using VBA code?**

Examples for Groups "Stainless Steel" and "Glass Dispenser":

Group **"Stainless Steel"**:
[image: stainless steel]

Group **"Glass Dispenser"**:
[image: glass dispenser]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT:**
Trying to create a macro based on @BruceWayne formula.

Getting an error for the line:

```
Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX('Script to organize Group'!R2C[1]:R469C[1],SMALL(IF('Script to organize Group'!R2C:R469C=MID(CELL(""filename"",R[-1]C),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-1]C))+1,255),ROW('Script to organize Group'!R2C:R469C)-ROW('Script to organize Group'!R2C)+1),ROWS('Script to organize Group'!R2C[1]:RC[1]))),"""")"
```

Note: Also tried using `Range("A2").FormulaArray = _` instead of `Selection.FormulaArray = _`, but still getting the same error.


My attempt at VBA code, using the formula, below:

```
Sub CategorizeKeywordsIntoGroups()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet     'Set the exact sheet, not just the one that is active _
                                        'and then you will go through all the sheets

    Range("A2").FormulaArray = _
        "=IFERROR(INDEX('Script to organize Group'!R2C[1]:R469C[1],SMALL(IF('Script to organize Group'!R2C:R469C=MID(CELL(""filename"",R[-1]C),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-1]C))+1,255),ROW('Script to organize Group'!R2C:R469C)-ROW('Script to organize Group'!R2C)+1),ROWS('Script to organize Group'!R2C[1]:RC[1]))),"""")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A9999"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("A2:A29").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In each of your worksheets that is named after a Group, place this in A2:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B$2:B$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!A$2:A$7=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),ROW(Sheet1!A$2:A$7)-ROW(Sheet1!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!B$2:B2))),"")`

This assumes you have the file saved somewhere.  Enter this as an array (with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) and drag down.  You will have to adjust the ranges of course.  But, as you add Group/Keywords, the lists will update automatically.  Also, to return say Currency or Avg. Month, just change the first Index range from `B$2:B$7` to whatever new range, i.e. `C$2:C$7`.

edit: Change "Sheet1" to the main sheet with all your data:
`=IFERROR(INDEX('Script to organize Group'!B$2:B$469,SMALL(IF('Script to organize Group'!A$2:A$469=MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,255),ROW('Script to organize Group'!A$2:A$469)-ROW('Script to organize Group'!A$2)+1),ROWS('Script to organize Group'!B$2:B2))),"")` and again, don't just press ENTER, press and hold CTRL+SHIFT, then ENTER.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to code it in VBA? I was trying to create a VBA code, I'll try to see if I can create a macro with that

Comment: Why in VBA? Are you making this part of a macro? Pretty easy, you'll want to set up some variables then for the lastRow probably. At the very least, you can go to Options --> Formulas --> R1C1 style.  You can then copy the formula and use `Cells(1,1).FormulaR1C1 - "=IfError( ...`  Or, another way to do it, is start recording a macro, *then* go in and enter the formula, drag down, etc. and then view the macro to see how the formula is written.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, yes- making it part of a longer macro - I will try those suggestions :)

Comment: Not sure how to make it work... when I paste the data it prompts me for a file location, and when I select the workbook I have open, and to Select a Sheet (it gives me a list of my Groups), but it doesn't fill in any data. I also tried CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER at various points but that didn't get anything to change or pop up.

Comment: @sikorloa - Ah, sorry, you'll want to change/remove/edit the `Sheet1!` part. Again, if your sheet has been saved, the above should work without any prompts to open a workbook and choose a worksheet.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, still trying to get it to work, I replaced 'Sheet1!' with 'Script to organize Group'! for every instance in that formula, and pasted it in 2nd worksheet (Stainless Steel) - The first keyword "stainless steel wire" did populate, but I couldn't get any more to populate. Is there anything I should change "filename" to in the formula? Also, cannot get 'CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER' to have any effect.

Comment: @sikorloa - Hm - See my edit, good call on the Sheet1 replacement. I downloaded the file and entered the formula exactly as I put in my new edit, in cell A2, of sheet "Stainless Steel", entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, then I'm able to drag down to get the different keywords.

Comment: Thanks Bruce for the clarification, I did get it to work when I entered it manually. Tried to record a VBA macro and create a subroutine from it, however I'm getting an error message on one of the lines. (Original post edited to include my attempt at code). Think you could provide any suggestions? :)